# SQL Select with multiple search parameters using joins and subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have spent hours searching for an answer for my problem without satisfying results.

I want to select everything with one query from players, villages and alliances -tables and date and population from histories table.

Selection must be filtered with following rules:

1. Select latest information by date.
2. **Select only if player has <= number of villages at the moment.**
3. **Select only if total population of player's villages is <= at the moment**

   1. and 3. are the ones causing my head hurt. How to add those to my query?

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT players.name AS player, 
       players.uid as uid, 
       players.tid, 
       villages.name AS village, 
       villages.vid as vid, 
       villages.fid as fid, 
       alliances.name AS alliance, 
       alliances.aid as aid, 
       SQRT( POW( least(abs($xcoord - villages.x),
                        400-abs($xcoord - villages.x)), 2 ) + 
             POW( least(abs($ycoord - villages.y),
                        400-abs($ycoord - villages.y)), 2 ) ) AS distance
FROM histories
LEFT JOIN players ON players.uid = histories.uid
LEFT JOIN villages ON villages.vid = histories.vid
LEFT JOIN alliances ON alliances.aid = histories.aid
LEFT JOIN histories h2 
       ON ( histories.vid = h2.vid AND histories.idhistory < h2.idhistory )
WHERE h2.vid IS NULL
  AND histories.uid != $uid
  AND SQRT( POW(least(abs($xcoord - villages.x),
                      400-abs($xcoord - villages.x)), 2 ) + 
            POW(least(abs($ycoord - villages.y),
                      400-abs($ycoord - villages.y)), 2 ) ) < $rad
ORDER BY distance
```

Notice: xcoord and ycoord are posted from the search form.

Example output:

```
PLayer| Village | Alliance | Distance

P1    | V1      | A1       | 1  
P2    | V4      | A2       | 2  
P1    | V2      | A1       | 3  
P1    | V3      | A1       | 4  
P2    | V5      | A2       | 5
```

Thank you in advance for helping. :)

This query can find players that have less than 2 villages. I just cant put my original query and this together. Is it even possible?

```
SELECT
b.*, count(b.uid) as hasvillages
FROM 
histories b
WHERE 
b.vid IN (SELECT a.vid FROM villages a) 
GROUP BY 
b.uid
HAVING 
count(b.uid) < 2
```

[HERE IS THE LINK TO SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ee52/2)

[HERE IS THE LINK TO PICTURE OF MY DATABASE EER DIAGRAM](http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/7619/cqme.jpg)

Comment: Added some data to sqlfiddle. You can test my query there now. Could some subqueries do the trick?

Comment: I don't know about everyone else, but I'm pretty confused about your question. What is the input to your query? I see that $xcoord and $ycoord are inputs. Are those the only search parameters? Also, what does histories mean? I assume there can be multiple rows in histories for any given date. Is each date a complete view of the global state, or do you need to piece together multiple dates to form a complete view? Regarding 2 and 3, <= is a binary operator. I don't see the two things that you are comparing.

Comment: Is 't' short for 'team'? Is 'f' short for 'field', or something like that?

Comment: tid = tribeid (can be 1, 2, or 3) fid = fieldid (this doesn't matter). My input for the query are numbers. They work as search parameters. Histories table updates daily. uid = playerid, vid = villageid, aid = allianceid, date is the day the row was added, population is the population of the village. From histories table you can see how players village has grown. Has player been in any alliances and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one week of try-outs I have finally found the answer.
With this query I can use following search parameters:

1. Find latest rows by date
2. Find rows by limiting the number of villages the player has.
3. Find rows by limiting the total population of villages the player has.
4. Find rows by calculating the distance.
5. Exclude players or alliances from selection.

Here is the query

```
SELECT players.name AS player, players.uid as uid, players.tid, 
villages.name AS village, villages.vid as vid, villages.fid as fid, 
alliances.name AS alliance, alliances.aid as aid, 
SQRT( POW( least(abs(100 - villages.x),400-abs(100 - villages.x)), 2 ) + 
POW( least(abs(100 - villages.y),400-abs(100 - villages.y)), 2 ) ) AS distance
            FROM histories
            LEFT JOIN players ON players.uid = histories.uid
            LEFT JOIN villages ON villages.vid = histories.vid
            LEFT JOIN alliances ON alliances.aid = histories.aid
            WHERE histories.uid IN 
                     (SELECT b.uid FROM histories b
                      WHERE (b.vid IN (SELECT a.vid FROM villages a) and b.date
                      in (select max(date) from histories))
                      GROUP BY b.uid HAVING count(b.uid) < 4 AND
                      sum(b.population) < 2000)
       AND histories.uid != 1
       and histories.date in (select max(date) from histories)
       AND SQRT( POW( least(abs(100 - villages.x),400-abs(100 - villages.x)),2)+ 
       POW( least(abs(100 - villages.y),400-abs(100 - villages.y)), 2 ) ) < 200
       ORDER BY distance
```